# How can I repeat a loop if the user asks so?

Tags: c#, console

How can I repeat a loop if the user asks so?

you can see what I did so far.
This is a Tic tac toe game.

The loops are in while(true) now. But I want to change it so when the game ends the program asks the users if they want another game.
So far I didn't managed to do so.

As you can see, the first loop clearing the console and initializing the game board. Then the second loop display the board and keep getting moves from the users etc.
There is a method that asks the users if they want to play again in `IfWinning` and `IsTie` methods. 
I want the program to ask the user if they want to play again an then exit the second loop and restart the first loop.

thank you

```
static Game G = new Game();
\\\Game is a class

try{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        G.StartingGameBoard();

        while(true)
        {
            G.BoardDisplay();

            G.Playing(G.ChecksException());
            G.BoardDisplay();

            G.IfWinning();

            G.IsTie();
            G.CurrentPlayer = G.GetTheNextPlayer(G.CurrentPlayer);

        }   
    }  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What's `G`? This isn't very clear.

Comment: Game G = new Game();

Comment: These sort of arguably elementary questions are not the place for SO.  Consider a good _Learning c# 101_ book or tutorial.  I wish you well

Comment: Firstly, please use `game = new Game();`, anyone reading you code will thank you for it. Next read up on `Console.ReadKey(true)` for how to get input from the user and replace `while(true)` with an eg y/n test

Comment: @MickyDuncan - I disagree, all questions are welcome provided they follow the guidelines, are clear, show research effort, and potentially useful. Although this question doesn't show all that much research effort.

Comment: Declare a boolean type variable and initialize it with false and place it in while. 
If user want to play more assign false to the bool variable. T
his way condition of while loop will be changes and control will come out of second loop.

I hope this'll work for you.

Comment: I know I am new to this but i did researched. my problem was the two loops i could not find how to repeat the first loop. it did start again but without initializing the new game.

Answer (score -1):

All you would need to do is use `Console.ReadKey()`

```
    try{
        bool ReRunGame = false; <<<<
        do
        {
            Game G = new Game();

            Console.Clear();
            G.StartingGameBoard();

            while(true)
            {
                G.BoardDisplay();

                G.Playing(G.ChecksException());
                G.BoardDisplay();

                G.IfWinning();

                G.IsTie();
                G.CurrentPlayer = G.GetTheNextPlayer(G.CurrentPlayer);

            }   

            Console.WriteLine("Play another game?");
            ConsoleKeyInfo ck = Console.ReadKey();
            ReRunGame = (ck.Key == ConsoleKey.Y);

        }while(ReRunGame);  <<<<<
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```